# Is there any feature for plotting level curves in pst-solides3d

Tags: pst-solides3d

Does `pst-solides3d` **still** have a mechanism for plotting level curves?

I say "still" because of the following lines in the manual

---

### Changes compared to version 3.0

- Suppression of the argument `tracelignedeniveau`

---

which (I guess) roughly translates to

- *trazar lineas de nivel* => *trace level curves*

So, is this a dead feature? is it comming back? where is it **if** it is still there? how does/did it fare in comparison with *implicit plot* from `pst-func`?

Comment: `pst-solides3d` is a sophisticated package but with very "confusing" key-value naming convention such as `grille`, `vecteur`, and many more (I cannot remember them). We are forced to learn a new language. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use `Div` which does the test for a zero division:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psset{viewpoint=50 300 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSurface[
    ngrid=0.2 0.2,incolor=darkgray,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    intersectiontype=0,
    intersectionplan={ %lets make some planes from 0-1 with 0.25 step
        [0 0 1 -0.00]
        [0 0 1 -0.25]
        [0 0 1 -0.50]
        [0 0 1 -0.75]
        [0 0 1 -0.95]}, %close enough to 1
    intersectionlinewidth=1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5,
    intersectioncolor=(red)(green)(blue)(cyan)(magenta)](-3,-3)(3,3){
      x x mul y mul 2 mul 
      x 4 exp y 2 exp add  Div }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't recall `Div` from **PostScript**. Is it defined in `solides3d.pro`?

Comment: in `pstricks.pro`

Answer (score 0):

I knew I would find a solution eventually

The family of options `intersection~` are an impressive tool for tracing level curves on solids and surfaces.

- `intersectiontype`, set to 0 to activate
- `intersectionplan`, add flat surfaces of the following type `ax+by+cz+d=0`. Leave the definitions as follows `[a b c d]`

As an example I will use a surface on which I'm working on and leave the level curves on it for your amusement

```
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psset{viewpoint=50 300 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSurface[
    ngrid=0.2 0.2,incolor=darkgray,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    intersectiontype=0,
    intersectionplan={ %lets make some planes from 0-1 with 0.25 step
        [0 0 1 -0.00]
        [0 0 1 -0.25]
        [0 0 1 -0.50]
        [0 0 1 -0.75]
        [0 0 1 -0.95]}, %close enough to 1
    intersectionlinewidth=1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5,
    intersectioncolor=(black)(black)(black)(black)(black)
](-3,-3)(3,3){
    /denom x 4 exp y 2 exp add def
    /numer x x mul y mul 2 mul def
    denom 0 eq {0} {numer denom div} ifelse %gotta fix that div/0
}
\end{pspicture}
```

I think this will amuse anyone looking for a way to draw level curves. The planes I used on this example are all horizontal (`z=k`) but tweak it to whatever you need.

Any comments are welcome